# Keep bottom content scrollview visible when soft keyboard is displayed

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I have a ScrollView that I am trying to use to replicate the accepted behavior of a text messaging app. When the ScrollView is first loaded, I scroll to the bottom. And when the soft keyboard is brought up, the ScrollView adjusts its height to compensate. But when the height of the ScrollView is reduced, the bottom contents are hidden, instead of the top contents. I would like for the contents to be pushed up as the size is reduced.

Now I could scroll to the bottom as soon as the ScrollView is re-sized, but what if the ScrollView is not already scrolled to the bottom? Essentially, I want to keep the last visible text message that the user is looking at visible, regardless if it is at the bottom of the ScrollView or not.

I've also tried using the ADJUST_PAN layout parameter, but I don't want my whole window panned up. But if there is an analogous ScrollView behavior, that is exactly what I'm looking for.